# python: how can i make turtle perform certain actions from a list?

Tags: python, list, turtle-graphics

```
data_sets = [
    ['O', ['Sheet C', 'Location 2', 'Upright'],
          ['Sheet B', 'Location 3', 'Upright'],
          ['Sheet D', 'Location 1', 'Upright'],
          ['Sheet A', 'Location 4', 'Upright']]
    ['X', ['Sheet A', 'Location 1', 'Upright'],
          ['Sheet B', 'Location 2', 'Upright'],
          ['Sheet C', 'Location 3', 'Upright'],
          ['Sheet D', 'Location 4', 'Upright']],
]
```

i need to be able to paste the correct sheet to the correct location. my current code is able to go to the right location but it can only paste up sheet_a_upright() and not the sheet that i want for example it works with this list, but then it pastes up one extra sheet:

```
data_sets = [
    ['O', ['Sheet A', 'Location 1', 'Upright']]
]
```

the code can paste to the correct location but it doesn't paste up the right sheet. if i make it paste one of the first 2 lists i put at the start of the question, it will only paste sheet A in all 4 locations. 
my code is as follows:

```
def goto_loc(data_sets):
    for location in data_sets:
        if len(location)>1 and 'Location 1' in location[1]:
            goto(-300, 0)
            sheet()
        elif len(location)>1 and 'Location 2' in location[1]:
            goto(-100, 0)
            sheet()
        elif len(location)>1 and 'Location 3' in location[1]:
            goto(100, 0)
            sheet()
        elif len(location)>1 and 'Location 4' in location[1]:
            goto(300, 0)
            sheet()

#function for which sheet should be drawn from data_sets
def sheet():
    for style in data_sets:
        if len(style)>1 and 'Sheet A' in style[1]:
            sheet_a_upright()
            return True
        elif len(style)>1 and 'Sheet B' in style[1]:
            sheet_b_upright()
            return True
        elif len(style)>1 and 'Sheet C' in style[1]:
            sheet_c_upright()
            return True
        elif len(style)>1 and 'Sheet D' in style[1]:
            sheet_d_upright()
            return True

#define sheet outline and fill
def outline():
    pencolor('black')
    penup()
    forward(100)
    pendown()
    fillcolor('green')
    begin_fill()
    left(90)
    fd(250)
    left(90)
    fd(200)
    left(90)
    fd(500)
    left(90)
    fd(200)
    left(90)
    fd(250)
    right(90)
    penup()
    end_fill()

#function for sheet A in upright position
def sheet_a_upright():
    outline()
def sheet_b_upright():
    outline()
def sheet_c_upright():
    outline()
def sheet_c_upright():
    outline()


# Paste the sheets onto the billboard as per the provided data set
def paste_up(data_sets):
    for each in data_sets:
        goto_loc(data_sets)
        if sheet():
            return
#the number i put into data_sets[] depends on which list i want to paste
paste_up(data_sets[0])
```

how can i get my code to paste the right sheet in the right location and then stop pasting once its at the end?(i diddn't include the code for the sheet A drawing because its too long and not important, the outline function is just to draw a border around the location)

Answer (score 0):

First, you appear to have mistyped - sheet_c_upright() is defined twice.

Second, all your sheet functions call outline() - is this intentional? If not, this might be why the same sheet is being drawn in all the locations.

Comment: the outlines are intentional, i diddnt include the drawing code for sheet a cos it just a long piece of turtle instructions. the problem seems to be with the goto_loc() and/or sheet() definitions cos the code can only seem to paste up sheet_a_upright().